# Lazy loading with DI into base class

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

**Situation:**

I have a base class `Base`.  `Main` extends `Base`.  `Main` passes a service in to `Base` via `super()`.  `Base` then calls a method on that service.

**Problem:**

The service is `undefined` in `Base`.  Unless I `console.log(_service)` prior in the base class.  I suspect a race condition related to lazy loading via AsyncRoute, or maybe its an instantiation issue...  either way, I'm not sure how to even start correcting it.

**Main.ts:**

```
export class Main extends Base {
    constructor(private _service:SomeService) {
        super(this._service);
    }
}
```

**Base.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class Base {
    constructor(_service) {
        _service.doSomething(true);
    }
}
```

The code blows up at `_service.doSomething(true)` with error:

> EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Main!
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'doSomething' of undefined

But if I try to trace why _service is undefined doing the following - magically it works???

**Base.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class Base {
    constructor(_service) {
        console.log("_service?", _service); // if this is here...
        _service.doSomething(true);  // ...then the error no longer occurs here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a static service, so I should have been doing `SomeService.doSomething()` instead of trying to instantiate it like `_service:SomeService`.

That's why the `console.log` "fixed" it - it was being instantiated within the `console.log()` statement, and then existed in time for the actual usage of it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use interface for the service to resolve this issue as follows.

```
interface IService{
   doSomething();
}
```

Now modify the base class as follows.

```
export class Base {
constructor(_service: IService) {
    _service.doSomething(true); 
  }
}
```

Note: The `SomeService` should implements `IService`
Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I should have included the service class - it was static, which was the problem.  See my answer.  Thank you for the help.